# How to represent a multiple in the frequency domain

Tags: waves, geophysics, frequency

So, in my previous question [Where does this formula for prediction of a multiple wave come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/where-does-this-formula-for-prediction-of-a-multiple-wave-come-from), I get that using this picture:

[image]

we have so far written the time it takes for a multiple to travel in the form:

$$T_2 = T_1 + \left( \frac{1}{v} \frac{2h}{\cos (\theta)} \right)$$

where

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{h}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4} + h^2}}.$$

AFter substituting in for $\cos(\theta)$, this can then be re-written as

$$T_2 = T_1 + \sqrt{\tau^2 + \frac{x^2}{v^2}}$$

where $\tau = \frac{4h^2}{v^2}$. From here though, it then says that we can represent this in the frequency domain as:

$$R h(\omega) e^{2 \pi i f (T_1 + \sqrt{\tau^2 + \frac{x^2}{v^2}}}$$

where $R$ is some constant including decay and $h(\omega)$ is the source wavelet.

I don't understand how they have managed to transform the previous equation into this one. Where has the exponential come from?

Comment: It doesn't look like they *transformed* the equation for $T_2$ *into* that, it looks like they *inserted* $T_2$ into a *different* equation.

Comment: @KyleKanos Is it a typical equation that you use to convert to frequency domain?

Comment: It does have the typical form of a Fourier series.